# Using docusign-java-client and ApiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow how do I get the token expiration?

Tags: java, rest, sdk, docusignapi

I am following the example for JWT Auth and getting a new token each time. I need to be able to request a new token only when the current one is about to expire. The examples do not show how to access this information and the methods exposed in the api do not seem to apply. Does anyone know how to use the api to get this or am I going to have to track it manually?

Comment: You've got to send a refresh token.

Comment: @Sjoerd de Wit - I would prefer to request it only when the previous token is ready to expire, not every single time we call the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JWT then you will be getting response like below:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eX...AnHDQ0bbA",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

It returns `expires_in` value in seconds, this will help you in knowing when the token is about to expire, also you should know the expiry time because while creating JWT you would have populated `exp` claim attribute in JWT and this `exp` time is your token expiry time.

Comment: I am using the configureJWTAuthorizationFlow method of the  com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient class from this example: [link] (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client#usage). It doesn't give access to the expiration.  At the moment, I am overriding the class to add a getter for the expiration, but had hoped there was a better way.

Comment: When you are calling `apiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow(publicKeyFilename, privateKeyFilename, OAuthBaseUrl, IntegratorKey, UserId, 3600)`, the last parameter is the value in seconds for expiry. So you are setting the expiry value in the call and same value you can use to create logic for calling new accesstoken.

Comment: So basically, track it manually. I thought perhaps the api would provide something in the authorization object, but evidently not.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are not using SDK then you can get it in the API response. Since you are using SDK, so I dont think there is any way to get expiry time.